# 2 way ssl handshake failure for API integration

Tags: ssl, https

Trying to integrate some APIs and landing into a handshake failure error. i don't know where i am going wrong.

here is the curl request

```
curl -v -k --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' https://10.156.145.219:8017 --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' --data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ns0:getfinancialresourceinformationrequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.ericsson.com/em/emm/serviceprovider/v1_0/frontend">
> > > <resource>fri:000001@ens.esdsacco/SP</resource>
> > > <accountholderid>ID:256780292729/MSISDN</accountholderid>
> > > <extension>
> > > <requestType>msg</requestType>
> > > <operationType>LOANAPPLICATION</operationType>
> > > <amount>6000</amount>
> > > </extension>
> > > </ns0:getfinancialresourceinformationrequest>' --cacert 63.35.60.38-testbed.crt
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: https://10.156.145.219:8017/
*   Trying 10.156.145.219...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.156.145.219 (10.156.145.219) port 8017 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: 63.35.60.38-testbed.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
```

The server is requesting a client certificate for mutual authentication but you don't provide one. Therefore the server will abandon the handshake. Check your API documentation of what kind of client certificate is expected and where do you get it.

Comment: There could have been permission problems with the files since i am reading from  file not keystore. i changed the permissions and now it works. thanks